# Python Pandas sort by column, but keep index same

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I created a data frame that consists of a Country, deal_category, and some_metric.

It looks like

```
    Country     metric_count    channel
0   Country1    123472          c1
1   Country1    159392          c2
2   Country2    14599           c3
3   Country2    17382           c4
```

I indexed according to Country and channel using the command

```
df2 = df.set_index(["Country", "channel"])
```

This creates the following dataframe.

```
            metric_count
Country     channel     
Country1    category1   12347
            category2   159392
            category3   14599
            category4   17382

Country2    category1   1234
```

Here's what I want to do. I'd like to keep this structure the same and sort according to the metric counts. In other words, I'd like to display for each country, the top 3 channels based on the metric count.

For instance, I'd like a dataframe to display for each country, the top 3 categories ordered by descending metric_counts.

```
Country2    top category1   12355555
            top category2   159393
            top category3   16759
```

I've tried sorting first, then indexing, but the resulting data frame no longer partitions based on country. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some taxing experimentation, I was able to get exactly what I wanted. I outline my steps below

1. Groupby Country

   ```
   group = df.groupby("Country")
   ```

   At a high-level, this indicates that we would like to look at each country differently. Now our goal is to determine the top 3 metric counts and report the corresponding channel. To do this, we will apply a sort to the resulting data-frame and then only return the top 3 results. We can do this by defining a sort function that returns only the top 3 results and use the apply function in pandas. This indicates to panda that "I want to apply this sort function to each of our groups and return the top 3 results for each group".
2. Sort and return top 3

   ```
   sort_function = lambda x: x.sort("metric_count", ascending = False)[:3]
   desired_df = group.apply(sort_function)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby/apply` to sort each group individually, and pick off just the top three rows:

```
def top_three(grp):
    grp.sort(ascending=False)
    return grp[:3]
df = df.set_index(['channel'])
result = df.groupby('Country', group_keys=False).apply(top_three)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)
N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country': np.random.choice(['Country{}'.format(i) for i in range(3)], size=N),
    'channel': np.random.choice(['channel{}'.format(i) for i in range(4)], size=N),
    'metric_count': np.random.randint(100, size=N)
})

def top_three(grp):
    grp.sort(ascending=False)
    return grp[:3]

df = df.set_index(['channel'])
result = df.groupby('Country', group_keys=False).apply(top_three)
result = result.set_index(['Country'], append=True)
result = result.reorder_levels(['Country', 'channel'], axis=0)
print(result)
```

yields

```
                   metric_count
Country  channel               
Country0 channel3            93
         channel3             0
         channel1             5
Country1 channel0            46
         channel2            86
         channel2            41
Country2 channel0             4
         channel0            51
         channel3            36
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I didn't get the exact right answer with your approach, but it provided the necessary insight for me to make some tweaks and ultimately get the right answer.